# ExtJs reload grid with extra parems

Tags: javascript, extjs

Proxy params are lost when load grid store with pagination bar refresh.

How can I give params for proxy?

I have tried

```
Ext.apply(commandGrid.store.getProxy().extraParams, {
    data: me.selectedItem,
});
```

and this

```
commandGrid.store.load(
     { params:{data: me.selectedItem},
           scope: this,
           callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                console.log(success);
            }
});
```

How can I set params before load store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do that in the [`beforeload`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-beforeload) event of your store.

If you insist on doing it *only for the paging toolbar* reload, override the [`doRefresh`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/Paging.html#Ext-toolbar-Paging-method-doRefresh) method of the paging toolbar instead.

Comment: Hi rixo,I want to do this for Extjs3.4 grid also,there is no options for do this please give me some suggestions.